# Css/Html remove space inbetween left side border and my unordered list

Tags: html, css, border, space

Hey I need help to remove space inbetween the left side border and my unordered list. The text inside the list has also been edited, so I tried to remove the tags connected to the list and it worked, but I want to also have the text styled.

Here is my css for the list:

```
#list {
text-indent: 150px;
list-style-position: inside; 
font-size: 35px; 
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 50px;
}
ul {
display: inline-block;
border: 5px solid red;
padding: 1px;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
     -moz-padding-start: 0px;
          padding-start: 0px;
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<h1 id="headline">5 Must Climb Mountains</h1>
<ul id="list">
<li>Kilimanjaro</li>
<li>Table Mountain</li>
<li>Matterhorn</li>
<li>Denali</li>
<li>Cerro Torre</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove `text-indent` or make it `0px` it will work'

Answer (score 0):

You have `text-indent: 150px` on your `#list`

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkunzokc/1/) which fixes it by removing that. [Text indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) will apply to any textual content of an element, including some tags such as `<li>`.

Comment: thanks man :D, also how can I move the whole box with the text?

Comment: @Olaflol positioning the box is achievable in a number of ways, it depends really on the context